# dimensions error

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I have to admit that I am quite new to eagle and that I am about to create my very first PCB.
However, I ran into an error I do not understand.

I do use 10x1 pinheads from the pinhead library, but when placed on the board they create a dimensions error (red marks next to the pin pads). The outer line is from the type 20 Dimensions, the inner line is a 21tPlaces line. No matter where I move the pins on the board, the error never changes.

I am sure it is a very simple problem, nevertheless I couldn't figure it out with google.

Thank you for your help!

[image: screenshot with red error marks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the two connectors on either side of the board are too close to the board edge.  How close traces are allowed to be to the edge is a parameter you set in the DRC.  To fix this, either fix the minimum clearance required in the DRC if it is set to large, or move the connector, then re-run DRC.

Separate issues:

What's with the oblong shape of the connector pads?  It seems silly at first glance.

Did you really mean for the SOT-89 IC and the few other parts with blue pads to be on the bottom of the board?  Unless you have a good reason, keep all parts on the same side.  That makes it cheaper to build and easier to debug.

Comment: The oblong shape gives high separation between adjacent pads while still giving a lot of area to hit with your soldering iron.

Comment: @Austin: Those pads are already very large, being 100 mil pitch, so even a 10 mil ring around the hole would be plenty easy to solder.

Comment: I agree, they are cheater pads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figuered out that the error occured because, like you said, I placed the connectors to close to the dimension layer. However, my real mistace was to not run the DRC again, so EAGLE showed me the old DRC errors over and over again even though I replaced the connectors.

What I am about to do with this project is to create a socket board for my Iridium 9603 module which has a very tiny connector (SS4-10-3.00-L-D-K-TR)that could not be soldered "in the air" (8.75mil distance between pads).

Comment: Furthermore I think you are right and I will place the LDO circuit also on the top and enlargen my board a bit. ;)